# Twig find if a css class exists in a tag

Tags: theming

Is there a way to find out if a css class exists in a specific tag through twig?

For example:

```
<body class="new-class">
```

Then I'm able to do a conditional statement in twig based if `new-class` exists.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You could use **hasClass** to find the CSS class in a specific tag

eg. `{% if body.attributes.hasClass('new-class') %}`